# What does "exclusion of the defence of continuation of the offence" mean?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

Could you please explain what this clause (from an employment contract) might mean:

> For every case of culpable violation of the obligation of
>   confidentiality stipulated in section xx, the Employee is obliged
>   ***under exclusion of the defence of continuation of the offence*** to  pay
>   a contractual penalty of ...

Comment: It means you shouldn't sign that contract without a lawyer. If a lawyer is too expensive, you shouldn't sign the contract.

Comment: To the close voter, this question is not asking for legal advice; it's asking for an explanation of a legal text.

Comment: Upon quick search, this phrase seems to arise almost-exclusively in English translations of German contracts, which might help someone who is more dedicated.